# Issue with "Link to Document" Content Type (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type, document

I am using a "Link to Document" content type in a document library (SP2013 Foundation) and the behavior is weird...when I select *NEW/Link to Document*, I am prompted to "Choose a file", as if using a *Document* content type, rather than just prompting for a URL and text as expected.

[image: Content Type]

[image: Adding Document, when it should be just a link]

Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, I found the solution...somehow the "Link to Document" content type TEMPLATE had been blanked out. I changed it back to "**/_layouts/15/NewLink.aspx**" and all is well!.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution...somehow the "Link to Document" content type TEMPLATE field had been blanked out. I changed it back to "**/_layouts/15/NewLink.aspx**" and all is well!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the "Link to Document" content type as the default content type on the Document library? If not, set as default and you should be prompted to enter a URL instead of a file. You can also select the new "Link to Document" content type from the "New Document" button on the ribbon menu.

If this doesn't work, have you tried removing and adding the content type?

Comment: It is not meant to be the default...I am using the NEW button on the menu. I have just tried removing and re-adding the Content Type...same behaviour. Thank you, but not solved yet.